# Efficient conversion of HashSet list to a single HashSet

Tags: c#, algorithm, hashset

I'm wondering what's the most efficient (edit: **fastest**) way of converting `IEnumerable<HashSet<T>>` to a single `Hashset<T>` with all its elements.

Sample situation:

Providing:

```
    class Rectangle
    {
        public HashSet<Point> PointSet { get; set; }
    }
```

Implement efficiently:

```
    HashSet<Point> ExtractUniquePoints(IEnumerable<Rectangle> rectangles) {}
```

Inefficient solution:

```
    HashSet<Point> ExtractUniquePoints(IEnumerable<Rectangle> rectangles)
    {
        HashSet<Point> uniquePoints = new HashSet<Point>();

        foreach (Rectangle rectangle in rectangles)
        {
            foreach (Point point in rectangle.PointSet)
            {
                uniquePoints.Add(point);
            }
        }

        return uniquePoints;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "most efficient"? Less code? Faster code? Less memory? Less GCs?

Comment: I posted an answer, but I read your question again and now I'm confused so I removed my answer. Your question seems to be more complicated than simply combining an array of HashSets into a single HashSet, correct? You actually need some logic in here, right?

Comment: do you actually have a performance bottleneck?

Comment: @Enigmativity I meant faster, edited.

Comment: @John was right, I've refactored the question since provided sample situation requires extra logic.

Comment: It is very unlikely to significantly improve code you have in the post as you already acting on each point once and using `foreach` instead of LINQ...If you believe there is particular piece of your code that does not perform well and have some reasoning for it to be faster - add that to your post. I think the real change would have to be level above for  overall algorithm which should be separate question (maybe even of CS or SoftwareEngeneering SE sites)

Comment: `SelectMany()` was what I was trying to find, but you're right that the performance I was expecting requires facing my problem with a different approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's necessarily a faster way to do what you're doing (at least not with HashSets), but a shorter method is the following:

```
HashSet<Point> ExtractUniquePoints(IEnumerable<Rectangle> rectangles)
{
    return new HashSet<Point>(rectangles.SelectMany(r => r.PointSet));
}
```

Or if you're using .NET Core, simply:

```
HashSet<Point> ExtractUniquePoints(IEnumerable<Rectangle> rectangles)
{
    return rectangles.SelectMany(r => r.PointSet).ToHashSet();
}
```